# android change start activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

I am new to android so I want to change the starting of the application in android manifest but each time the application is stopped cs worked is that we must change the java codes aussie
here is the xml code:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="hello">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ServersActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="standard">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.AddServerActivity"
            android:label="@string/add_server_label">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="irc"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting the starting activity, you'll have to add the following `Intent Filter` to the activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Please note that you should only add this `Intent Filter` to one of your Activities. Otherwise, you might experience unexpected behaviours.

There is no way to change the starting activity by code.

Comment: I did exactly like that and it works at the beginning and the interface appeared after but when I click the botton application stop working

Comment: There must be another bug in your code. If the right activity starts. that means the intent filter above works. Please accept this answer by clicking the checkmark to the left in case it solved the original Problem.

Comment: Yes, but that is not related to the code above. That's a separate Problem and I'd suggest opening a new question for that. Also make sure to include the LogCat there.

Comment: the console show le this status [2014-01-28 14:37:50 - Yaaic] Android Launch! [2014-01-28 14:37:50 - Yaaic] adb is running normally. [2014-01-28 14:37:50 - Yaaic] No Launcher activity found! [2014-01-28 14:37:50 - Yaaic] The launch will only sync the application package on the device! [2014-01-28 14:37:50 - Yaaic] Performing sync

Answer (score 0):

Cut this line and paste it inside activity tag to whom you want as starting activity

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

For eg: Making AddServerActivity as stating activity

```
     <activity
        android:name=".activity.ServersActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="standard">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AddServerActivity"
        android:label="@string/add_server_label">
        <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="irc"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: yes I do like that excatly but the application is stopped working

Comment: I did exactly like that and it works at the beginning and the interface appeared after but when I click the botton application stop working

Comment: can you post your main activity.java?

Comment: I did exactly like that and it works at the beginning and the interface appeared after but when I click the botton application stop working  the console show le this status                                                                                                                [2014-01-28 14:37:50 - Yaaic] Android Launch!
[2014-01-28 14:37:50 - Yaaic] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-28 14:37:50 - Yaaic] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-01-28 14:37:50 - Yaaic] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2014-01-28 14:37:50 - Yaaic] Performing sync

Comment: @user3234804..post your current manifest.xml.it seems that you dint implemented it correctly